# How to configure maven-release to use Perforce as SCM provider?

Tags: maven, maven-3, perforce, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

I am trying to use the **maven release plugin** to create a released version of a Java project having **Perforce** as the SCM.

My pom scm section is:

```
<scm>
  <connection>scm:p4:myperforcehostname:1666://mydepot/mycomponent</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:p4:myperforcehostname:1666://mydepot/mycomponent</developerConnection>
  <url>http://myperforcehostname:1666</url>
</scm>
```

Also I use the **P4Maven** plugin and the Maven Release Plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.perforce</groupId>
      <artifactId>p4maven</artifactId>
      <version>[2011,2012)</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <configuration>
    <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
    <username>myusernme</username>
    <password>mypassword</password>
    <includes>**</includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>        
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</plugin>
```

When calling 'mvn release:prepare -DdryRun=true' I get

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare 
(default-cli) on project mycomponent: The provider given in the SCM URL could not be found: 
No such provider: 'p4'. -> [Help 1]
```

Any ideas?

I am able to call `mvn scm:checkout`.

Comment: It does work with `scm:perforce` instead of `scm:p4` though. At least if I have the `p4` command line client installed.
Maybe I got somethinh wrong: what is the p4maven plugin meant for? I do not need it if I use `scm:perforce`, do I?

Comment: Also I recognized that `scm:checkout` is not the same as _Get Latest Version_ in P4V. It just copied all files into the _target_ folder. Is there any good tutorial on how to use Maven with Perforce?

Comment: When using SCM provider `perforce` the `scm:checkout` just copies the files. If you want a correct Perforce sync you need to use P4Maven along with SCM provider `p4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that P4Maven comes not out of the box. I had to download it from the Perforce pages and install it into my repository (following the instructions in the download zip file). After that I could successfully use `p4` as the SCM provider.

Comment: I would expect that Maven would download the `P4Maven` plugin from one of its remote repositories. You might hadn't configured those correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `p4maven` as dependency to the `maven-scm-plugin` as well as to the `maven-release-plugin`.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.perforce</groupId>
      <artifactId>p4maven</artifactId>
      <version>[2011,2012)</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <configuration>
    <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
    <includes>**</includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>        
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- P4Maven -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.perforce</groupId>
      <artifactId>p4maven</artifactId>
      <version>[2011,2012)</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <configuration>
    <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
    <includes>**</includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I done recently:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.perforce.p4maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>p4maven-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.perforce.p4maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>p4maven-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

And then some useful commands:

```
mvn scm:changelog -Dusername=yourP4user -Dpassword=yourP4pwd
release:prepare -Dusername=yourP4user -Dpassword=yourP4pwd -autoVersionSubmodules=true -DignoreSnapshots=true
```