# Maven Release plugin error: Version was not mapped

Tags: maven, jenkins, perforce, maven-release-plugin

I'm using maven release plugin and I'm getting the following error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project ****: Version for '****' was not mapped -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project ****: Version for '****' was not mapped

I run the job from Jenkins and source code is in perforce.
What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Maven plugin but "mapped" in a Perforce context usually refers to a client view.  I'm guessing the plugin is configured to use a particular client view to sync files, and the view does not include the project files that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your project to use perforce as an SCM - use the maven-scm-plugin and add the dependency to the P4Maven plugin.

See the [P4Maven manual](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4maven/index.html).

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814138/how-to-configure-maven-release-to-use-perforce-as-scm-provider).